# Spinner not showing list of items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a Spinner that is being populated by a custom adapter.

I can log out all the TextView's in the custom adapter and see what the text is at the position.

> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 0 TEXT: ABC Company
>
> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 1 TEXT: DEF Company
>
> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 2 TEXT: GHI Company
>
> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 3 TEXT: JKL Company
>
> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 4 TEXT: MNO Company
>
> TEXT VIEW AT POSITION 5 TEXT: PQR Company

So I know passing the data in isn't the problem.

When the Spinner is selected, in the app it just shows up blank.

***Anyone see what I am doing wrong?***

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Spinner spinnerCompanies;
    private ArrayList<HashMap> arrayOfCompanies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_call);

       spinnerCompanies = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCompany);

        //do background task and pass JSONArray to processCompanies
       processCompanies(jsonArray);

   }

    public void processCompanies(JSONArray jsonArray){

            arrayOfCompanies = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

            HashMap company;
            JSONObject record;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                record = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                company = new HashMap<String, String>();

                company.put("NAME", record.getString("CompanyName"));

                arrayOfCompanies.add(company);

            }

            CompanyAdapter companyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(arrayOfCompanies);
            spinnerCompanies.setAdapter(companyAdapter);

            spinnerCompanies.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    didSelectCompany(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
    }

    private void didSelectCompany(int position){
        Log.i(TAG, "didSelectCompany: " + position);
    }

    public class CompanyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final ArrayList<HashMap> mArrayList;

        public CompanyAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap> map) {
            mArrayList = map;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
            return mArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_company, parent, false);
            }

            HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTermainalName);
            textView.setText(item.get("NAME"));

            Log.d(TAG, "TEXT VIEW AT POSITION " + position + " TEXT: " + textView.getText());


            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

**R.layout.item_company XML** used by the custom adapter

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvSubTermainalName"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: one issue could be, use  `return position;` in `getItemId`

Comment: That did not work @PavneetSingh

Comment: isn't the log `Log.i(TAG, "didSelectCompany:` is working because right now `onItemSelected`  code is just displaying a log

Comment: Nothing appears in the Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the part

```
if(convertView==null)
```

and try inflating the view always?